# How to get image name in Google Cloud Platform Kubernetes Pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

How do you get the **digest** of a container image running on a **pod** in [[image]kubernetes](/questions/tagged/kubernetes)?

Based on the screen-shot below, I would like to be able to retrieve `d976aea36eb5` from the pod *(logs, YAML etc. whatever is the way to get it)*

What I can get from `YAML://Deployment/spec/template/spec/containers/image` is `mysolution.host` which is the common name of the image.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this isn't possible via the kubernetes API, you can do it through the docker registry API.

What you're looking for is the image's **digest**, which is the sha256 hash of its [manifest](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/manifest-v2-2/). The "Name" column in the screenshot of GCR's UI is the truncated digest of the image.

The string `us.gcr.io/my-project-37111/mysolution.host` represents a **repository**, which is just a collection of images. These images can be referenced by their digest or by a tag.

You can list all the tags in your repository using gcloud:

```
$ gcloud container images list-tags us.gcr.io/my-project-37111/mysolution.host
```

That will show you the truncated digest as well. For the full digest, you can use the `--format=json` flag:

```
$ gcloud container images list-tags --format=json us.gcr.io/my-project-37111/mysolution.host
```

If you happen to know the tag (`0.0.5-linux` for the highlighted image), you can call the registry API directly:

```
$ curl \
  -H "Accept: *" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
  -I https://us.gcr.io/v2/my-project-37111/mysolution.host/manifests/0.0.5-linux |
  grep "digest"
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed information.  I may miss explained what I'm trying to do.  I need to get that `digest` info for the running pod. Assume that I set the `active` tag on 0.0.5 and run the pod, then change the `active` tag and added on 0.0.6.  I would like to know if running pod is 0.0.5 or 0.0.6 at that point.

Comment: Does this work?

`kubectl get pod $POD -o jsonpath="{...imageID}"`

Comment: yes it did work, `status/containerStatuses/imageID` includes that info.  Thank you very much